# Solving Lagrange Multiplication Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Optimize $f(x,y,z)=25x^\frac 25y^\frac 15z^\frac15$ with the constraint $24000=80x+12y+10z$

New to Lagrange, I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: What *do* you know about the method of Lagrange multipliers? You have to show some effort, not just "Do this standard homework problem for me" if you expect good responses on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of the function is given by: $\bigtriangledown$ f= $\langle\frac{10y^\frac15z^\frac15}{x^\frac35},\frac{5x^\frac25z^\frac15}{y^\frac45},\frac{5x^\frac25y^\frac15}{z^\frac45}\rangle$

The gradient of the constraint is given by $\bigtriangledown$ g= $\langle80,12,10\rangle$

 Since $\bigtriangledown f=\lambda \bigtriangledown g$

 $80\lambda=\frac{10y^\frac15z^\frac15}{x^\frac35}$ which we can simplify as $\lambda=\frac{10y^\frac15z^\frac15}{80x^\frac35}$

 $12\lambda=\frac{5x^\frac25z^\frac15}{y^\frac45}$ which we can simplify as $\lambda=\frac{5x^\frac25z^\frac15}{12y^\frac45}$

 $10\lambda=\frac{5x^\frac25y^\frac15}{z^\frac45}$ which we can simplify as $\lambda=\frac{5x^\frac25y^\frac15}{10z^\frac45}$

 Since we have all of our terms equivalent to $\lambda$, we can set the terms equivalent to each other and solve for a variable. We can begin by setting the first two terms equivlent to each other.

$\frac{10y^\frac15z^\frac15}{80x^\frac35}=\frac{5x^\frac25z^\frac15}{12y^\frac45}$

 Some cross multiplication and some algebra leads us to the fact that:

$120yz^\frac15=400xz^\frac15$

$x=\frac{120}{400}y$

 Since we now have x in terms of y, we need z in terms of y so that we can plug it back into our original constraint. So lets solve for z in terms of y by setting the last two terms equivalent to each other, like so:

 $\frac{5x^\frac25z^\frac15}{12y^\frac45}=\frac{5x^\frac25y^\frac15}{10z^\frac45}$

 Some cross multiplication and some algebra leads us to the fact that:

$50x^\frac25z=60x^\frac25y$

$z=\frac{60}{50}y$

 We now have x and z in terms of y, and since y is already in terms of y, we can plug everything into our original constraint.

 $80(\frac{120}{400}y)+12y+10(\frac{60}{50})y=24000$

 $24y+12y+12y=24000$

 $y=500$

 Now that we have a value for y, and we have x and z in terms of y, we can just plug in y and find the values of x and z.

 $x=\frac{120}{400}(500)=150$

 $y=500$

 $z=\frac{60}{50}(500)=600$

 Plugging the x,y,z we found into our original function

 $f(150,500,600)=25(150)^\frac25(500)^\frac15(600)^\frac15=2311.00435152$

 Looking at our function, there is no lower bound therefore our maximum is given by $f(150,500,600)=2311.00435152$

Comment: I would recommend using `\nabla` to produce $\nabla$. I would also avoid using <br></br>.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to get more practice writing with LaTeX.